# Store data from several tables in one variable with a single database call (Rails)

Tags: ruby-on-rails, database

Assume these models:

```
class User < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :posts
end

class Post < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :user
  has_many :sections
end

class Section < ActiveRecord::Base
 belongs_to :post
 has_one :user, :through => :post
end
```

Assume this controller:

```
class SectionsController < ApplicationController
  def latest_sections
    @sections = Section.select(:name, :position, :updated_at)
                       .where(:public => true)
                       .order("updated_at DESC")
                       .limit(5)
  end
end
```

And finally this view:

```
<ul>
  <% @sections.each do |section| %>
    <li>
      <h1>Section updated on: <%= section.updated_at %></h1>
      <%= section.position %> - <%= section.name %>
      <% post = section.post; user = section.user %>
      From Post: <%= link_to post.name, post %>
      By User: <%= link_to user.username, user %>
    </li>
  <% end %>
</ul>
```

My problem:

This causes several database calls for the `post` and `user` variables I am declaring in the view for each cycle of the `each` loop.

Is there a way for me to include all **and only** the information I need for the code above to work with a single database call and store it in the `@sections` variable (I'm assuming this will work with a joins).

In order words, I want to store this information in the `@sections` variable in a single database call:

- section's `name`
- section's `updated_at`
- section's `position`
- section's user's `username`
- section's user's `url_for`
- section's post's `name`
- section's post's `url_for`

And how would I access this information?

(Note: none of this is specific to my case, it's just a generic example for a larger scenario)

Answer (score 0):

It seems to me You are asking about includes option.

```
Section.includes(:posts, :user).find(1)
```

Comment: Yes, but this will store all of the fields `post` and `user`. Wouldn't it be more efficient to specify the fields that I need in the query, or am I wasting energy trying to figure this one out? Thanks.